# 「LINEで送る」でURLを送ったときAndroid版のみトーク上でリンクにならない

Tags: android

MONACAアプリでLINEで送るを実装し、URLスキームをメッセージとして送信した場合、iOSでは送られてきたLINEのトーク内でURLスキームがリンクになりアプリを直接開けるのですが、アンドロイド端末のLINEではURLスキームがリンクになりません。

もちろん、webのアドレスはリンクになりタップできます。

LINEで送るを利用しアンドロイド端末でもURLスキームをリンクにする方法をご存知なら教えてください。

Answer (score 0):

まず、「LINEで `twitter://hoge` といったURLを送ってもリンクにならない」件については、あなたのプログラムの問題というよりLINEの問題ですから、LINEのサポートに問い合わせてはいかがでしょうか。

もしLINE側ではどうしようもないとなれば、 `http(s)://` でなんとかするしかないでしょう。

- そのURLでアクセスしたWebページからリンクやJavascriptでアプリを起動
- `http://hogehoge` を拾うようにインテントフィルタを設定する

後者の方法は iOS では実装できませんから、相手の環境を気にせず送るためには前者の対応が必要になるような気がします。